# Timeout while uploading files to azure storage

Tags: powershell, azure, blob, azure-storage

I am getting timeout error while uploading a zip file to azure storage using Powershell

Command used:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 
storageaccount -StorageAccountKey "SomeKey"

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob storageaccount -Container 
artifactscontainer "F:\ABC\DEF\DEF.zip" -Context $context -Force
```

The error I am getting is :

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout.
```

## NOTE:

File size is 50 MB

Comment: have you tried to set the default time out interval?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure PowerShell module older than 4.3.1, download the latest module from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/4.3.1) ,retry the operation and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Didn't worked even after installing the latest module :(

Answer (score 0):

According to your Error, this issue may caused by Exeptions to Default Timeout Interval of your Blob Service Operations.

Ensure your local network is OK and your firewall allow this traffic. Then you can use try this solution:
You can use

`-ClientTimeoutPerRequest`  to specifies the client-side time-out interval, in seconds, for one service request. If the previous call fails in the specified interval, this cmdlet retries the request. If this cmdlet does not receive a successful response before the interval elapses, this cmdlet returns an error. You can just increated the timeout from 90 sec to 600 sec.

**Example:**

```
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob storageaccount -Container artifactscontainer "F:\ABC\DEF\DEF.zip" -ClientTimeoutPerRequest <Int32> -Context $context -Force
```

More about **-ClientTimeoutPerRequest** , refer to this official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-4.3.1#optional-parameters

More about setting default timeouts for blob service operations , refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/storageservices/setting-timeouts-for-blob-service-operations